# How to make retry in Spring TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Following the code which I did for the Async mail sending using Spring 3 TaskExecutor. Code is working fine, I just want to know if any mail failed to sending by any reason then it must be added into queue again and sending must be retried.

I have Googled but did not get information for retry policy.

Help will be highly appreciated !!!

```
@Service
public class AsyncMailSender implements MailSender {

    /* Logger for Search-Controller Class */
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AsyncMailSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    public void send(SimpleMailMessage simpleMessage) throws MailException {
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        modelMap.put("user", "Manoj");
        simpleMessage.setText(VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "templates/email.vm", modelMap));
        taskExecutor.execute(new AsyncMailTask(simpleMessage));
    }

    public void send(SimpleMailMessage[] simpleMessages) throws MailException {
        for (SimpleMailMessage message : simpleMessages) {
            send(message);
        }
    }

    private class AsyncMailTask implements Runnable {

        private SimpleMailMessage message;

        private AsyncMailTask(SimpleMailMessage message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            LOGGER.info("Sending Emails" + message.getSubject());
            mailSender.send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, currently there is no way to configure retries with Spring 3 TaskExecutor, there is a [SPR](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6860) associated with that. Having said that, I think Spring retries the method automatically if any exception is thrown. If the exception keeps on recurring, this can be problematic for you (in terms of resource consumption).

Comment: Thanks for such a great info, i went SPR as well. Would like know is there any way to configure number of retry, so if same error occured then after some number Spring will not execute that task again.

Comment: That's exactly the SPR is about and it is unresolved. I don't think there is any built-in way to configure that, you might need to code up your application to take care of those things.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be ideal, but you can use [Spring-Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) inside your task like this:

```
@Service
public class AsyncMailSender implements MailSender {

    @Autowired
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    private class AsyncMailTask implements Runnable {

        private SimpleMailMessage message;

        private AsyncMailTask(SimpleMailMessage message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, PersistenceException>() {

                    LOGGER.info("Sending Emails" + message.getSubject());
                    mailSender.send(message);

                    return null;
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

you can configure the RetryTemplate like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RetryConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

        RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();

        TimeoutRetryPolicy policy = new TimeoutRetryPolicy();
        policy.setTimeout(30000L);

        template.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        return template;
    }
}
```

You might also find [Spring-Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring doesn't do that for you**

You have to do the exception handling and queuing yourself. The `TaskExecutor` itself is inherently retry-capable as it just runs your task at the next configured interval not matter what.